# Ctrl-e and Ctrl-a not working on Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, readline

I use a Mac, so I don't have <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys on my keyboard. I also SSH to Linux servers quite a bit. I've found that when I SSH to an Ubuntu Linux server running Jaunty I can use the readline key-bindings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to move the cursor to the beginning or the end of the line, but there are a couple of Hardy servers I often SSH to, and those key-bindings don't work when connecting to them.

I've tried connecting to them from a Linux box instead, just in case it was something to do with the way my Mac Terminal is configured, and I see the same results.

Does anyone have any idea why, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just a thought, but try entering this and retrying the commands:

```
set -o emacs
```

If that works, put the setting in your *~/.bashrc* file to load it automatically.

If you prefer vi(m), you can do this:

```
set -o vi
```

Note, however, that the vi-bindings aren't nearly as complete as the emacs ones.

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer! /etc/bash.bashrc had `set -o vi` in it, which for some reason was preventing Ctrl-e and Ctrl-a from working.

Comment: The `set -o vi` command causes Bash to use Vim bindings. The default is Emacs style bindings. So, it's not "for some reason," but rather that `set -o vi` invokes a whole different set of Readline options. See my answer for how to switch on the fly.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I realised that Bash was being set to use vi bindings, but didn't expect that to prevent Ctrl-a and Ctrl-e from working. I'd not realised that the way to turn-off vi bindings was to set emacs bindings.